# Iterative methods to solve an ill-conditioned linear system

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I am currently solving a problem that in the process ends up having to solve a linear system with a symmetric matrix. The matrix of this system is not always positive-definite, and at most this matrix can be positive semi-definite.

In the case that the matrix is positive-definite, I use a Cholesky decomposition in the matrix to solve the system. In the other case, I'm using a [Conjugated Gradient Least Square](https://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/cgls/) algorithm, but I don't know if it's the best way out. I was trying to avoid regularization (Tikhonov/ridge) in this type of problem, because it slows down my algorithm by searching the most suitable value for the regularization parameter.

Anyone know or could give me suggestions/algorithms for a linear system whose matrix is positive semi-definite?

Answer (score 0):

While is not an iterative method, one way to go is to use the [Moore-Penrose generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) . You might find this slow, though, especially if your matrix is large.

In the context of least squares, if A^ is the generalized inverse, then

```
A^*b is the (unique) minimiser of || A*x-b|| where x itself is of minimum norm
```

Many libraries will have a function that solves least squares through use of this inverse; a clue is whether they say they use the SVD.

If you have to write some of this yourself, the steps are, so solve Ax=b:

```
Diagonalize A as A = U*D*U'
compute c = U'*b
compute the generalised inverse E of the diagonal matrix D by replacing elements that are too small by 0 and the others by their inverse
compute c = U*(E*c)
```

However this does require diagonalizing A, which might be slow.